# Iterate through a hashmap?

Tags: java, list, loops

I am trying to make kind of highscores in Java.
Basically I want a hashmap to hold the double value (so index starts from the highest double, so it's easier for me to sort highscores) and then the second value will be the client object, like this:

```
private HashMap<Double, TempClient> players = new HashMap<Double, TempClient>();
```

And to insert a new value:

```
        TempClient client = new TempClient(kills, rank, deaths, name);
        this.players.put(client.getKdr(), client);
```

Now, of course I can't iterate through the hashmap because it gets the list item by key, not index.

How can I iterate through a hashmap? or any good ideas for my case?

I tried it in a Foo class:

Output:

```
0.5
0.6
0.9
0.1
2.5
```

Code:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Double, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Double, String>();
        map.put(0.5, "hey");
        map.put(0.6, "hey1");
        map.put(0.9, "hey2");
        map.put(0.1, "hey425");
        map.put(2.5, "hey36");
        for (Double lol : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(lol);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is Double the score in this case? Or a playerID

Comment: Looking up Kdr, it sounds like that is indeed score, the way HashMaps work the Double is the key to the TempClient, if several TempClient's have the same Kdr then the HashMap will only keep one

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate like this.

```
for (Double k : players.keySet())
{
    TempClient p = players.get(k);
    // do work with k and p
}
```

If you want to keep keys sorted, use e.g. a TreeMap.
If you want to keep the keys in the order you inserted 
them in there, use e.g. a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: As peter.petrov said, loop over the keySet and for each key, fetch the value from the HashMap.

Comment: Yeah but the hashmap is not sorted? it ouputs the double 0.1, then 0.3, then 0.9 ten 0.6 then 0.2?

Comment: NVM: Jigar's linked hashmap with this fixes it I think.

Comment: Read my edited question, I've added code, but it does not sorts them by biggest double

Comment: @user3123545 Use TreeMap if you want them sorted.

Comment: @user3123545 Btw, as others pointed out, if two players have the same score and your Map key is indeed the palyer's score, you have a problem with this kind of Map you're using. If so, I suggest you post another question about this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to iterate through hashmap is using EntrySet.

```
for (Map.Entry<Double, TempClient> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Double  key= entry.getKey();
    TempClient value= entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off making your TempClient objects implement Comparable, adding them to a list, and then just using Collections.sort().

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't sort items in a `HashMap`, nor you can sort them by value in a `TreeMap` you could use a `TreeSet` with a custom class:

```
class Score implements Comparable<Score>
{
  final Player player;
  final int score;

  Score(Player player, int score) {
    this.player = player;
    this.score = score;
  }

  public int compareTo(Score other) {
    return Integer.compare(this.score, other.score);
  }

  public int hashCode() { return player.hashCode(); }
  public boolean equals(Object o) { return this.player.equals(...); }
}

TreeSet<Score> scores = new TreeSet<Score>();
score.add(new Score(player, 500));

for (Score s : scores) {
  ..
}
```

This will have both the advantages:

- it will be iterable
- it will keep scores automatically sorted

It should work easily with consistente between `equals`, `hashCode` and `compareTo` but maybe you should tweak something (since it's untested code).